# Setting maven post build event in TFS 2012 for running Selenium tests in Java

Tags: maven, selenium, tfs

We are an automation test team of 3 SDETs writing E2E Selenium Tests for our web portal using Java and we use Maven as the build tool.

The web product that we test is developed using C# and .NET platform. So, the developers are using TFS 2012 server & TFS controller for the continuous integration of the builds and maintaining their source code.

The code for our Automation Tests live in BitBucket and we use our local machines to run our Maven builds.
In the near future, we will have our own Test Server to run the automation tests.

My question here is:
Whenever there is a new build available, the Test server is deployed with the latest build. At that point, we need to trigger our Automation Tests automatically (may be from TFS 2012, but not sure yet)
What kind of setup do we need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Check this blog: https://blogs.infosupport.com/running-java-builds-using-team-foundation-build/. If you use the new build system of TFS 2015 or VSTS, to test java application will be easy: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/continuous-test-java

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. But this is only possible for TFS 2015, not for TFS 2012.

Comment: What's the OS on your automation test server?

Comment: Hi @Eddie-MSFT We are using Windows Server 2012 as our test server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using TFS as a CI, but the way we do it in teamcity is:

- The build configuration for the application kicks off to build new changes.
- When application build is complete and successful it kicks off the build configuration for automation tests.

The way that happens is in the build configuration for automation tests have settings for build triggers, which is set to a successful build of the application.

To make this possible using maven, at least for teamcity, it required a maven plugin so teamcity knows what to do with the custom build command line parameters.

Such as:

```
mvn clean test
```

Unfortunately, as I mentioned, I had have an personal experience with TFS CI setup, but I suppose it may be very similiar to how TC and Jenkins CI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, mvn plugin is only available for TFS 2015, but not for 2012.

Comment: Nobody can help around that outside your office. Perhaps it is more incentive to upgrade or use a different CI. Another thing though, it is possible tfs has built in support for maven. I'd check into that.